# Parse json data from APIgive bad formated data

Tags: php, curl

I want to parse this json data from [here](https://play.esea.net/api/teams/8755001/matches)
I got this data successfully in browsers.
But I want to scrape this data using curl  or any other method in php.
My code for scraping in PHP using curl is

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: play.esea.net';
$headers[] = 'path: /api/teams/8755001/matches?page_size=50';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
 $url="https://play.esea.net/api/teams/8755001/matches";
 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);
```

This code runs successfully but give results in some Unicode like ��)J��l�Ȳ

Any one tell me what is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: The site requires a javascript security check. You will not be able to access it via curl.

Comment: I also use ajax request but not get data. Can you explain please.

Comment: esea.net has protections against third party access. You will not be able to use this page the way you want.

Comment: is it imposible to use this page using programming,?